# SqlDataAdapter.update() not updating database

Tags: sql, ado.net, sqlcommandbuilder

I am searching for (PostId,UserId) into PostLikes table using `SqlDataAdapter`, if the row is found , I am using `SqlCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand()` to generate  the delete instruction and deleting the underlying row, if the row is not found, then I use `SqlCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand()` to generate the insert command and inserting the row to the table using `SqlDataAdapter.Update()`. But the row is not getting inserted to the table in database. Here is what I have done so far

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionStrings);
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter=new SqlDataAdapter("select * from PostLikes where PostId like "
                                                 +postlike.PostId+" and UserId like "
                                                 +postlike.UserId,con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Result");
con.Open();
SqlCommandBuilder sqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter);
if(ds.Tables["Result"].Rows.Count==1)
{
    sqlDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = sqlCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand(true);
    msg = "Data is deleted";
}
else
{
    sqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = sqlCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
    msg = "Data is inserted";
}
sqlDataAdapter.Update(ds, "Result");
```

and the table
PostLikes(LikeId,PostId,UserId)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

- You are looking to reuse the same command to both detect whether the row exists, and to supply to the `SqlAdapter` for the `SqlCommandBuilder`.
- You should parameterise the initial select query to protect against SqlInjection attacks (and there is a minor performance benefit). The CommandBuilder will automatically parameterize the `Insert` / `Delete` commands
- After creating the Insert / Delete commands with the `SqlCommandBuilder`, you then need to change the underlying dataset in order for any changes to be made to the table during the `Update`.
- Note that many of the Sql objects are `IDisposable` and should be disposed ASAP - `using` scopes help here.

.

```
var postId = 1;
var userId = 1;
string msg;
using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"data source=..."))
using (var selectCommand = new SqlCommand(
 "select LikeId, PostId, UserId from PostLikes WHERE PostId=@PostId AND UserId=@UserId", con))
using (var sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand))
using (var ds = new DataSet())
{
    con.Open();
    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostId", postId);
    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Result");
    using (var sqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter))
    {
        if (ds.Tables["Result"].Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            sqlDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = sqlCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand(true);
            ds.Tables["Result"].Rows[0].Delete();
            msg = "Data will be deleted";
        }
        else
        {
            sqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = sqlCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
            // Null because LikeId is Identity and will be auto inserted
            ds.Tables["Result"].Rows.Add(null, postId, userId);
            msg = "Data will be inserted";
        }
        sqlDataAdapter.Update(ds, "Result");
    }
}
```

I've assumed the following Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE PostLikes
(
    LikeId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    PostId INT,
    UserId INT
)
```

And I've assumed you want to 'toggle' the insertion or deletion of a row with the `postId, userid` combination.

Comment: is con.Open() is necessary with SqlDataAdapter?

Comment: Good point - no, it can [detect the closed connection and open it automatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377a8x4t.aspx). But obviously, you'll need to manually open the connection if you also use just the basic / direct `SqlCommand`